# Laravel Eloquent for pivot table with 2 foreign keys to a table and 1 foreign key to another table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, laravel-7

I have tables as follows where `role_id` is the foreign key of the `roles` table and `user_id` and `setter_id` are the foreign key of the `users` table.

```
table 1:
+---------------------+
| users               |
+---------------------+
| id                  |
| name                |
| email               |
| password            |
+---------------------+

table 2:
+---------------------+
| roles               |
+---------------------+
| id                  |
| name                |
+---------------------+

pivot table:
+---------------------+
| role_user           |
+---------------------+
| role_id             |
| user_id             |
| setter_id           |
+---------------------+
```

The models I have defined:

**User Model:**

```
class User extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    
     public function roles()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
     }
}
```

**Role Model:**

```
class Role extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

How do I change my models so that I can get the data as shown below?

user -> roles -> setter : The user and its roles and the setter of each role for user

Thank you...

Comment: Please refer to this. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will never be able to access the setter by calling it in the roles collection.

This is wrong:

```
$user->roles->setter
```

Let's see an example that will work:

```
foreach($user->roles as $role)
{
    dd($role->pivot->setter)
}
```

To be able to do that, you need to change your models to reflect something like this:

**User**

```
class User extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    
     public function roles()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)
            ->using(UserRolePivot::class)
            ->withPivot([
                'role_id',
                'user_id',
                'setter_id',
            ]);
     }
}
```

**Role**

```
class Role extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)
            ->using(UserRolePivot::class)
            ->withPivot([
                'role_id',
                'user_id',
                'setter_id',
            ]);
    }
}
```

**Pivot**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class UserRolePivot extends Pivot
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'role_id',
        'user_id',
        'setter_id',
    ];

    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class , 'role_id');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class , 'user_id');
    }

    public function setter()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class , 'setter_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i get this using with() in a controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can either update the `belongsToMany` calls to include the setter_id on the pivot aswell, and then access it via `->pivot->setter_id` and retrieve a model using that id.

```php
return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)->withPivot('setter_id');
```

Or (and what I would personally go for) you could [define a custom pivot model](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models), and create a `setter()` relationship there, so you could retrieve the model directly from the pivot.